# Unable to create Azure AKS Container Service with Managed Identity using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to create an instance of AKS Container Service with managed identity using an ARM template.
No problems if I use the az CLI:

`az aks create -g "sa-rg" -n "aks-cluster" --enable-managed-identity`

However I cannot obtain the same result using an ARM template.

Let's consider the following base ARM template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "outputs": {},
  "parameters": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "location": "australiaeast",
      "name": "aks-cluster",
      "properties": {
        "agentPoolProfiles": [
          {
            "name": "agentpool",
            "count": 1,
            "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
            "osType": "Linux",
            "osDiskSizeGB": 128,
            "`": null,
            "osDiskType": "Managed",
            "maxPods": 110,
            "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
            "mode": "System"
          }
        ],
        "dnsPrefix": "aks-cluster-dns",
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "clientId": "msi",
          "secret": null
        },
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
        "enableRBAC": true
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters"
    }
  ]
}
```

According to https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12219#issuecomment-636143374, to create with managed identity (MSI), only the "identity" object should be needed, not "servicePrincipalProfile". But, if I do so, I get the following exception:

> ERROR: {"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The
> template deployment is not valid according to the
> validation procedure. The tracking id is
> '5a6c6444-c74b-4709-888e-bef816d05ca9'. See inner errors for
> details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidParameter","message":"Provisioning
> of resource(s) for container service aks-cluster in resource group
> sa-rg failed. Message: {\n  "code": "InvalidParameter",\n
> "message": "**Required parameter servicePrincipalProfile is missing**
> (null).",\n  "target": "servicePrincipalProfile"\n }. Details:
> "}]}}

However, if I insert "servicePrincipalProfile" (as shown above), I get:

> ERROR: {"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The
> template deployment is not valid according to the
> validation procedure. The tracking id is
> '536bca0b-33b8-45f8-8407-edba873d3657'. See inner errors for
> details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidParameter","message":"Provisioning
> of resource(s) for container service aks-cluster in resource group
> sa-rg failed. Message: {\n  "code": "InvalidParameter",\n
> "message": "**The value of parameter servicePrincipalProfile.secret
> is invalid**. Please see https://aka.ms/aks-naming-rules for more
> details.",\n  "target": "servicePrincipalProfile.secret"\n }.
> Details: "}]}}

I have tried

```
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "clientId": "msi"
          "secret": null
        },
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
```

```
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "clientId": "msi"
          "secret": ""
        },
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
```

```
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "clientId": "msi"
          "secret": "dummy"
        },
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
```

```
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "clientId": "msi"
        },
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
```

and again the same 4 removing "identity", but I always get the **The value of parameter servicePrincipalProfile.secret is invalid**

***What is the right ARM template to create the Container Service?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

- The `identity` property should be at the root of the resource,
- You only need to specify `clientId: "msi"` in the `servicePrincipalProfile` property.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "outputs": {},
  "parameters": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "location": "australiaeast",
      "name": "aks-cluster",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "agentPoolProfiles": [
          {
            "name": "agentpool",
            "count": 1,
            "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
            "osType": "Linux",
            "osDiskSizeGB": 128,
            "osDiskType": "Managed",
            "maxPods": 110,
            "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
            "mode": "System"
          }
        ],
        "dnsPrefix": "aks-cluster-dns",
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "clientId": "msi"
        },
        "enableRBAC": true
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The servicePrincipalProfile is only used when you are provisioning a Service Principal outside of the ARM template and need to pass it's properties into the template.  In my deployments I've set this to an empty object though it could potentially be omitted entirely as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters?tabs=json#managedclusterproperties-object) says it's not a required property.

```
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {},
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
```

Though it's not documented in my experience you can also omit the identity property and it will default to SystemAssigned.

Comment: Does not work. I get "The value of parameter servicePrincipalProfile.clientId is invalid"

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying AKS using a template, and the template look like this.

```
{
  "name": "[parameters('Your-aks-name')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
  "apiVersion": "2021-07-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Basic",
    "tier": "Free"
  },
  "properties": {
    "kubernetesVersion": "1.20.7",
    "addonProfiles": { ..... },
    "enableRBAC": "[parameters('aks_enableRBAC')]",
    "dnsPrefix": "[variables('aks-dns-prefix')]",
    "agentPoolProfiles": [
      { .... }
    ],
    "servicePrincipalProfile": {
      "ClientId": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientId')]",
      "Secret": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientSecret')]"
    },
  }
}
```

So as you can see there, ClientId and Secret are needed.

And when I run, I get the following errors.

```
The value of parameter servicePrincipalProfile.secret is invalid. Please see https://aka.ms/aks-naming-rules for more details.
```

So I solved it as follows.

First create a service principle. Its given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal?tabs=azure-cli) in detail.

az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment --name vivek-globoticket-askcluster-sp

Note the app Id and password.

```
az ad sp show --id 67def144-ded3-4fe9-a2f1-cdec6689cd2e # use your app id here.
```

Also, once you create, you can see them in the azure portal as follows.
Search and go into Azure Active Directory blade.
Click on App Registrations and then All Applications or Owned Applications.

[image: Azure Active Directory Searching in Azure Portal]

[image: App Registrations in Azure Active Directory]

If you forgot to note down the password, then you have to delete the sp and then recreate it.

```
az ad sp delete --id a76ef144-dee3-4fe9-12f1-cdecn689cd2e # use your app id here.
```

So for servicePrincipalProfile in the Template do the this. For the client id, use AppId and for the secret, use the password.

Now try creating your aks and see what happens.